# Ubuntu - Install Alongside Windows 7

Tags: troubleshooting

I've got Windows 7 installed on my machine with the drive split in 3 partitions, the 2 that windows makes and 1 for backup. The drive has roughly 400gb unallocated space.

When attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS alongside Windows 7, I don't get the option, the installation setup says No Operating Systems detected.

Not exactly sure where to go from here.. I've tried deleting all the partitions and starting over, reinstalling Windows, but nothing seems to bring that menu option back.

Any suggestions?

-edit- I tried attaching a picture of the current partition setup but SE app is giving an error. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot from Ubuntu install media.
- Select <kbd>Try Ubuntu without installing</kbd>.
- Open <kbd>GParted</kbd> (Partitioning tool).
- Create a partition for Ubuntu (size that fits your needs).
- Create a swap partition (size minimum matching RAM).
- On the desktop click <kbd>Install Ubuntu</kbd>.
- Choose <kbd>Something else</kbd>.
- Select the partition you created for Ubuntu before.